# Android app using google maps and json for markers

Tags: android, json, google-maps

I tried to use the code provide on https://gist.github.com/TimPim/5902100 but the app would not run unless I commented out the lines

```
setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();
setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
if (map == null) {
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
.getMap();
if (map != null) {
setUpMap();
}
}
}
```

after that, the markers wouldn't show. I'm new to android developing so if anyone can help I'd appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Why won't the app run without these lines?

Comment: My LogCat was throwing the "java.lang.NullPointerException" Do you think that code is needed to display the markers?

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather add this as a comment but my reputation is too low for that, so:

If you comment all of that out, of course the markers won't show up: setUpMapIfNeeded() would call setUpMap() which would call retrieveAndAddCities() which would call createMarkersFromJson() which is where the Markers are created.

If that whole cascade is never triggered the Markers are not created and are therefore not shown.

Where do you get the NPE initially?

Comment: I suppose line 47 of your MainActivity is
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
.getMap();
Right? Are you sure that your fragment's id (in the layout xml) is indeed map? (android:id="@+id/map")

Comment: Also, if the id is indeed correct, maybe try to "clean project" - I sometimes get errors like that when I move around elements in the layout XML...

Comment: That worked. I changed that code to   map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();   and it did the trick!